# Divergent - unbounded sequences and l' Hopital's rule.

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I need to show that the sequence $(x_n) = c^n/√ n, |c|>1$ does not converge (the question actually asks me to prove that it does not converge to $0$, but I think I can prove that it does not converge to any number). My thought was to prove that it is unbounded and therefore it does not converge. So my question is, is proving that $lim(x_n) = ∞$ by the L'Hopital rule equivalent to proving that $(x_n)$ is unbounded? Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends on $c$.  if $c=0$ the limit is obviously $0$.  Indeed, if  $0≤c≤1$ the limit is  $0$.  For $c=2$ the answer is $\infty$.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention the important detail that $|c|>1 $

Comment: $\lim x_n = \infty$ implies $(x_n)$ is unbounded, but $(x_n)$ can be unbounded without $\lim x_n = \infty$ or even $\lim |x_n| = \infty$. For example, $$x_n = \begin{cases} n, & n \text { odd}\\0, & n \text{ even}\end{cases}$$